# Moving/Zooming a HTML element leaves border leftovers all over the place

Tags: html, css

I am working with my diagramming library in Blazor that uses HTML/CSS to display nodes and links. In one of my use cases, when I zoom out to the maximum and move a node around it starts to leave some "border leftovers" or residues all over the place. When I remove borders from the node's CSS, it doesn't.

The zoom is done using the `transform: translate(x, y) scale(f)` CSS function. Currently, the scale is 0.1, the elements appear very small but are still movable.

Moving a node is a simple change in its `top` and `left` CSS properties. As you can guess, the nodes have an absolute position. And they move on a div with `overflow: visible` since they can go over the limits.

Here's how the problem looks like:
[image]

Here's what a node looks like:

```html
<div class="node" style="top: 100px; left: 100px">
    <div class="content">
        OTHER STUFF
    </div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Border CSS:

```css
    border: calc(var(--node-border-width) + 3px) solid rgb(0, 120, 215);
    height: calc(100% + 2px);
    left: -1px;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem? It happens on both Chrome & Edge from my tests.

Comment: I have seen something similar and it appears to be 'part pixels' left behind (one whole CSS pixel being made up of several screen pixels). Can you put up a working snippet which shows the problem. For example is --node-border-width altered dynamically?

Comment: Hi @AHaworth, visit https://blazor-diagrams.zhaytam.com/demos/custom-group and zoom until the elements are very small, then start moving the green node (group)

Comment: Nothing is altered dynamically while the node is moving, except `top` and `left`.

Comment: I've tried on my laptop with Edge/Windows 10 and zoomed out and in and didn't see any stray lines with moving the green element a lot and fast/slow.... (I did manage to use 20% GPU). What OS/browser are you using?

Comment: Tested on both Edge & Chrome. Check this issue, it contains a very simple sample that reproduces the issue, and also some working fixes: https://github.com/Blazor-Diagrams/Blazor.Diagrams/issues/143